# access assets within css play framework

Tags: css, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

How do I refer to assets within a CSS file?

I am using Play Framework 2.1.3 (Scala).

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: RockSalt;
    src: url('...something.../assets/fonts/MyFont.ttf');
    format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing magic about this topic in Play , just use **relative** paths to your font files in your CSS file. ie. if you have `css` and `fonts` folders on the same level it will be:

```
src: url('../fonts/MyFont.ttf');
```

if you are using default route for assets it can be also path that is relative to app's root:

```
src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFont.ttf');
```

Comment: Absolute paths wont work- the point of doing @routes.Assets.at(...) in a view is because the app context is configurable. You can do something similar in js using the javascript router helper. I was just wondering if there is the same feature for working with css. I'll try a relative path.